# Analyzing Git(Hub) repos with Mathematica?

Tags: plotting

Are there libraries/facilities within the Wolfram language to view analytics on git repos? It would nice, for example, to use Wolfram charts to plot lines of code added/removed by a single contributor over time, and so forth.

Comment: I don't use it myself, so I don't know if it would help, but have you seen [GitLink](https://github.com/WolframResearch/GitLink)?

Comment: Here is a link to a related question [“Import and Plot Git Commit History”](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94706/). There are other related questions and answers for GitLink. Voting to close as a duplicate.