# Making a Stacked GitHub Bar Chart

Tags: charts

Here's a picture of what I mean by a stacked bar chart:

[image]

**Question:** For the following GitHub repos:

1. Organization1/Repo1 (branch: branch1)
2. Organization2/Repo2 (branch: branch2)

How can one make a stacked bar chart of the commits per day? So if, i.e., on 2019-07-08 we had 2 commits in the first repo and 3 commits in the second repo, then the bar chart should show 5 total commits on that date segmented across the two repos.

It would be nice also if we could limit this to a single contributor (say with username `contributor1`).

## Attempt

**EDIT:** I can use answers from elsewhere in this site to get part of this question answere, but not all of it. Suppose that we wish to pull data for

1. WolframResearch/WolframClientForPython
2. WolframResearch/WolframLanguageForJupyter

We can use

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/\
MathematicaForPrediction/master/Misc/GitHubPlots.m"];

Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/\
MathematicaForPrediction/master/Misc/GitHubDataObjects.m"];

reposToAnalyze = {"WolframClientForPython", 
   "WolframLanguageForJupyter"};

ghs = Map[MakeGitHubDataObject["WolframResearch", #] &, 
   reposToAnalyze];
ghComposite = GitHubDataComposite[Unique[], ghs];
ghComposite[
 "Plot3D"["ProjectPlanes" -> True, "GlobalTimeOrder" -> False, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 2, 2}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 1000}]]

ghDLPlots = 
  Map[GitHubDateListPlot["WolframResearch", #, 
     PlotLabel -> Style[#, "Subsubtitle"], 
     FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
     AspectRatio -> 4] &, reposToAnalyze];
Grid[{ghDLPlots}]
```

which yields:

> [image]
>   [image]

**Problems with this solution:**

1. There is no way (AFAIK) to get information on a particular branch (or for a particular contributor) using antononcube's (wonderful) library.
2. The graphs are segmented, when I'd like to view these parts as a "whole" (I think the stacked bar chart is the best way to do this, unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: Check the documentation for `BarChart` and the `ChartLayout` option.  Then armed with that information, please give an explicit example (i.e., *Mathematica* code you've tried) if things still don't plot the way you want.  Stacked bar charts are usually pretty poor at conveying the associated information:  https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/daviz/learn-more/chart-dos-and-donts#toc-16.

Comment: Related question: [“Import and Plot Git Commit History”](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94706/34008).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import and Plot Git Commit History](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94706/import-and-plot-git-commit-history)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for using that package!

> There is no way (AFAIK) to get information on a particular branch (or for a particular contributor) using antononcube's (wonderful) library.

Yes, there is an OOP method implemented for that. Using `ghs` from your code:

```
ghs[[1]]["CommitRecords"]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to isolate this data on a particular branch?